# android Dialog Dismiss -> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. when I using runOnUiThread

Tags: android, dialog, android-runonuithread

I am dismiss Dialog through RunOnUiThread.
However, the error message is as follows.
"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
Can I know what to do?

This is my code

```
appleLoginDialog?.let { dialog ->
            runOnUiThread {
                if (dialog.isShowing) {
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you certain that the error actually comes from that call to dismiss? (and not some other dismiss call you haven't wrapped in `runOnUiThread`)

Comment: you can paste in the stack trace to clarify Tyler's question.

Comment: Sorry, I solved it.
Issue is When I show Dialog
I use runOnUiThread
But, Answer is Using Handler
Cause is Handler is Queue.....